# nopCommerce Widget and Theme tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I'm looking for widget and theme implementation tutorial for Asp.Net Mvc.

I saw nopCommerce source code and seems they done it well.

Plugin system and Zone (positions) supported theme system. But after checking code im so confused.

Is there any tutorial explains nopCommerce plugin and theme system? Especially I love WidgetByZone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Designer%27s+Guide
After documentation I suggest to you download free theme and review its.